# Tool to transform latex table to org-mode table?

Tags: latex, org-mode

I have a relatively big latex table. Is there a tool that can help me transform it to org-mode?

Comment: see http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-latex-export.html

Comment: That would be the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) (GPL), *"a Haskell library for converting from one markup format to another, and a command-line tool that uses this library"*.

Comment: Tried Pandoc. It doesn't really convert tables well.

Comment: Another possibility with Pandoc is two steps: LaTeX -> HTML -> Org-mode.

Comment: There is also [M-x org-table-import](http://orgmode.org/org.html#Built_002din-table-editor) (after LaTeX -> tab-separated, etc.; see Stack Exchange's [Is there a way to compile a LaTeX table into tab delimited text?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26051/is-there-a-way-to-compile-a-latex-table-into-tab-delimited-text)). However, I would try first Pandoc's LaTeX -> HTML -> Org-mode.